# I2C PIC18F2520 and PI

Tags: python, i2c

I am having a big problem to communicate a PI with PIC using I2C.
When I try to use another PIC as master everything works fine, no problem. But swtich to PI I cant get it to work.

To start my both slave PIC uses adress 0xA0 and 0xA2, and when `i2cdetect -y 1` I get this results:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: 50 51 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I have made a very simple python code:

```
import smbus
import time
# for RPI version 1, use "bus = smbus.SMBus(0)"
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# This is the address we setup in the Arduino Program
address = 0x50
address2 = 0x51

while True:

    asd1 = bus.read_byte_data(address, 0x31)
    asd2 = bus.read_byte_data(address, 0x30)

    print
    test = (asd2 << 8) + asd1
    print test
    print
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

when I run the program, most of results are 0 and when get some number are completly different from when I get with PIC as master, witch is 0-1023
Here what I get:

```
0
0
0
0
18432
2432
47874
34837
3392
10771
5489
50506
6192
13699
272
8302
0
0
```

Thank-you

Comment: I've seen no evidence that the Pi's I2C is faulty.  So loose connections (post a photo of your set-up) seems most likely.

Comment: here is a photo of oscilloscope http://prntscr.com/5vzytp even when get 0 scope doesnt change..

Comment: Post a photo of your connections, i.e. the wires between the Pi and the PIC.

Comment: here the photos http://prntscr.com/5w02dl and http://prntscr.com/5w02jn could it be the Level Converter?

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what is going on.  You need ground, power, SDA, and SCL connected.  As long as the PIC does not have SDA/SCL pull-ups to 5V (which it should not have) you should not use a level converter.

Comment: On the PIC board has pull-ups to 5V...

Comment: Pity about the pull-ups.  In that case you need a level shift on SDA and possibly SCL.